# Find the first element that satisfies condition X in a Seq

Tags: scala, collections

Generally, how to find the first element satisfying certain condition in a `Seq`?

For example, I have a list of possible date format, and I want to find the parsed result of first one format can parse my date string.

```
val str = "1903 January"
val formats = List("MMM yyyy", "yyyy MMM", "MM yyyy", "MM, yyyy")
  .map(new SimpleDateFormat(_))
formats.flatMap(f => {try {
  Some(f.parse(str))
}catch {
  case e: Throwable => None
}}).head
```

Not bad. But 1. it's a little ugly. 2. it did some unnecessary work(tried `"MM yyyy"` and `"MM, yyyy"` formats). Perhaps there is more elegant and idiomatic way? (using `Iterator`?)

Comment: Use `find` method of `Seq`

Comment: Not the same, bu related: if you already have a `X => Option[R]` function (which decides the applicability of the function + does return the actual application/mapping), you can easily convert that function to a `PartialFunction`, thus then being able to use it for your sequence in `collectFirst`. See: `Function.unlift` (https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.x/#scala.Function$). -- More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908295/how-to-convert-x-optionr-to-partialfunctionx-r

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you're confident at least one will format will succeed:

```
formats.view.map{format => Try(format.parse(str)).toOption}.filter(_.isDefined).head
```

If you want to be a bit safer:

```
formats.view.map{format => Try(format.parse(str)).toOption}.find(_.isDefined)
```

[`Try`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.Try) was introduced in Scala 2.10.

A [`view`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/views.html) is a type of collection that computes values lazily. It will apply the code within the `Try` to only as many items in the collection as is necessary to find the first one that is defined. If the first `format` applies to the string, then it won't try to apply the remaining formats to the string.

Comment: This answer has two anti patterns: i) unexpected exceptions thrown in the Try will be lost, causing it to hide bugs and return incorrect answers (for example, what if the list if a view of a database?) ii) filter construct a temporary list and also requires that ALL elements are visited even if only the first is required. Its unnecessarily expensive in time, but particularly also in memory.

Answer (score 37):

You should use `find` method on sequences. Generally you should prefer built-in methods, because they might be optimised for a specific sequence.

```
Console println List(1,2,3,4,5).find( _ == 5)
res: Some(5)
```

That is, to return first SimpleDateFormat that match:

```
 val str = "1903 January"
 val formats = List("MMM yyyy", "yyyy MMM", "MM yyyy", "MM, yyyy")
   .map(new SimpleDateFormat(_))
 formats.find { sdf => 
      sdf.parse(str, new ParsePosition(0)) != null
 }

 res: Some(java.text.SimpleDateFormat@ef736ccd)
```

To return first date that has being processed:

```
val str = "1903 January"
val formats = List("MMM yyyy", "yyyy MMM", "MM yyyy", "MM, yyyy").map(new SimpleDateFormat(_))
val result = formats.collectFirst { 
  case sdf if sdf.parse(str, new ParsePosition(0)) != null => sdf.parse(str)
}
```

or use **lazy collection**:

```
val str = "1903 January"
val formats = List("MMM yyyy", "yyyy MMM", "MM yyyy", "MM, yyyy").map(new SimpleDateFormat(_))
formats.toStream.flatMap { sdf =>
   Option(sdf.parse(str, new ParsePosition(0)))
}.headOption

res: Some(Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 EET 1903)
```

Comment: I did provide full working example. Guy is asking how generally find the first element in a sequence.

Comment: here you go, the one with dates

Comment: That is not what the OP asked for; instead of returning the first successful parse result, you are returning the first `SimpleDateFormat` which parsed it.

Answer (score 10):

This prevents the unnecessary evaluations.

```
formats.collectFirst{ case format if Try(format.parse(str)).isSuccess => format.parse(str) }
```

The number of evaluations of the `parse` method is number of tries + 1.

Answer (score 5):

Just use find method as [it returns an Option of the first element matching predicate if any](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/#scala.collection.immutable.Traversable) :

```
formats.find(str => Try(format.parse(str)).isSuccess)
```

Moreover, execution stops at the first match, so that you don't try parsing every element of your set before picking the first one. Here is an example :

```
def isSuccess(t: Int) = {
  println(s"Testing $t")
  Math.floorMod(t, 3) == 0
}
isSuccess: isSuccess[](val t: Int) => Boolean

List(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90).filter(isSuccess).headOption
Testing 10
Testing 20
Testing 30
Testing 40
Testing 50
Testing 60
Testing 70
Testing 80
Testing 90
res1: Option[Int] = Some(30)

Stream(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90).filter(isSuccess).headOption
Testing 10
Testing 20
Testing 30
res2: Option[Int] = Some(30)

List(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90).find(isSuccess)
Testing 10
Testing 20
Testing 30
res0: Option[Int] = Some(30)
```

Note that for Stream it doesn't really matter.
Also if you are using IntelliJ for example it will suggest you :

> Replace filter and headOption with find.
>   Before:

```
seq.filter(p).headOption
```

> After:

```
seq.find(p)
```

Answer (score 3):

Same version with Scala Extractor and lazyness:

```
case class ParseSpec(dateString: String, formatter:DateTimeFormatter)


object Parsed {
  def unapply(parsableDate: ParseSpec): Option[LocalDate] = Try(
    LocalDate.parse(parsableDate.dateString, parsableDate.formatter)
  ).toOption
}


private def parseDate(dateString: String): Option[LocalDate] = {
  formats.view.
    map(ParseSpec(dateString, _)).
     collectFirst  { case Parsed(date: LocalDate) => date }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> def parseOpt(fmt: SimpleDateFormat)(str: String): Option[Date] =
     |   Option(fmt.parse(str, new ParsePosition(0)))
tryParse: (str: String, fmt: java.text.SimpleDateFormat)Option[java.util.Date]

scala> formats.view.flatMap(parseOpt(fmt)).headOption
res0: Option[java.util.Date] = Some(Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1903)
```

By the way, since `SimpleDateFormat` is non-thread-safe, that means the above code is not thread-safe either!

Answer (score 2):

I think using tail recursion is much better and by far the most efficient solution offered here so far:

```
implicit class ExtendedIterable[T](iterable: Iterable[T]) {
  def findFirst(predicate: (T) => Boolean): Option[T] = {
    @tailrec
    def findFirstInternal(remainingItems: Iterable[T]): Option[T] = {
      if (remainingItems.nonEmpty)
        if (predicate(remainingItems.head))
          Some(remainingItems.head)
        else
          findFirstInternal(remainingItems.tail)
      else
        None
    }
    findFirstInternal(iterable)
  }
}
```

It would allow you upon importing the above class to simply do the something like the following wherever you need to:

```
formats.findFirst(format => Try(format.parse(str)).isSuccess)
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Using org.joda.time:

**Definition**:

```
def getBaseLocalFromFormats[T <: BaseLocal](
                        value: String, 
                        validPatterns: Seq[String], 
                        parse: (String, String)  => T) : Option[T] = {
    validPatterns.view.map(p => Try{ parse(value, p) }).find(_.isSuccess).map(_.get)
  }
```

**Usage**:

```
getBaseLocalFromFormats( 
                "01/10/1980 16:08:22",
                List("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
                (v,p) => DateTimeFormat.forPattern(p).parseLocalDateTime(v))
```

```
getBaseLocalFromFormats( 
                "01/10/1980",
                List("dd/MM/yyyy",  "dd-MM-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"),
                (v,p) => DateTimeFormat.forPattern(p).parseLocalDate(v))
```