# Need efficient way to sort list of strings (dates) in Scala. (Avoiding the darkness of Java.)

Tags: string, list, scala, date, sorting

I'm looking for a functional way to **sort** Dates in Scala. The dates come in as a list of strings and need to return as a sorted list of strings.
The list of strings are of these formats:

```
"dd MMM yyyy"
"MMM yyyy"
"yyyy"
""
```

I have tried setting up a regex to parse for the day, month, and year.
I would then put them into year month day and use the .sorted .
This would however place 1 before 10 and couldn't handle the months.
Jan, Feb, ...

I then tried converting the strings into date classes but I couldn't find any way to sort them.

I have a considerable amount of data to sort. That would be the only consideration.

Thank you,
Erick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can correctly convert the list of `String` to a `List[Date]`, then you are really close.  From there, assuming the list is called `list`, you can sort by the epoch time of the dates:

```
  list.sortBy(_.getTime)
```

Comment: And this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16883858/2483228 might be useful in obtaining the list...

Comment: Thank you ^_^ I spent a considerable amount of time looking around and testing different things. The method would work if I converted everything to YYYYMMDD with the Month being changed to 01,02, etc...