# search sequence of sequences for single first match efficiently

Tags: scala, functional-programming, sequence

I want to figure out the single matching group.
As all groups are disjoint, only a single match is possible.
If no match is found `other` is returned.

A single match is enough. It is not efficient to search the whole sequence
How can the search be stopped after the first match?

How can this be written in a more scala-like/functional way which is less clumsy?

```
val input = 1
val groupings = Seq(Seq(1), Seq(2, 4), Seq(6, 7))

def computeGroup(input: Int, groups: Seq[Seq[Int]]): String = {
  val result = for (s <- groupings if (s.contains(input)))
    yield s
  val matchingGroup: Seq[Int] = result.flatten

  if (matchingGroup.isEmpty) {
    "other"
  } else {
    matchingGroup.mkString("-")
  }
}
computeGroup(1, groupings) // expected 1
computeGroup(2, groupings) // expected 2-4
computeGroup(5, groupings) // expected other
```

Following the advice of [Find the first element that satisfies condition X in a Seq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883591/find-the-first-element-that-satisfies-condition-x-in-a-seq)

```
groupings.find(_ == Seq(input))
```

partially works for `computeGroup(1, groupings)`. It is already better as it should stop after the first match.

```
Some(List(1))
None
None
```

Unfortunately, it will not (yet) handle the other cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't `_.contains(input)` do the [job](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ZI0oIqTRT6GkLtnXz5jJAA)?

```
val input = 1
val groupings = Seq(Seq(1), Seq(2, 4), Seq(6, 7))

def computeGroup(input: Int, groups: Seq[Seq[Int]]): String = groups
  .find(_.contains(input))
  .map(_.mkString("-"))
  .getOrElse("other")

computeGroup(1, groupings) // expected 1
computeGroup(2, groupings) // expected 2-4
computeGroup(5, groupings) //
```

It will stop after finding the first matching group.

Comment: indeed, this looks much cleaner